# Is there a way to retrieve the required roles of the current page with twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an `<aside>` block who display ads, as you probably know ads companies don't allow you to display these in a private environment like the places you need to authenticate, so i was looking for a smart way to disable those ads in the pages who require authentication from the user.

Also, i really don't like the idea of having two different file inclusions if the user is online or not, and its almost certain that there is an inline solution to solve this equation.. So is there a way to disable an item through twig if the "current" page require a given role, in my case ROLE_USER and above e.g.

```
<aside>
{% if not is_required('ROLE_USER') %} <-------- if the role ROLE_USER is not requiered -->
    <section id="my-ad">
    </section>
{% endif %}
    ...
</aside>
```

I know there is a function called `is_granted()`, but if i do this, the ads will be disabled on all the pages if the user is authenticated, even those who don't requiere authentication, and this is obviously not the wished behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use request attributes.

In your routing configuration, add for example a `hide_ads` attribute:

```
login_page:
    path: /login
    defaults:
        hide_ads: true
```

Then you can use it in you template with `{% if !app.request.attributes.has('hide_ads') %}`

Answer (score 0):

Not the optimal answer, but if you use access_control to filter pages which require authentication, there is a change you try to match a regular expression against the path of the page. You could try to use this same regular expression in your twig template.

Answer (score 0):

You should create spearate action which renders your aside block. In this action you should check if user is authenticated and other stuff. 
If user is authenticated just return new Response() otherwise return your rendered view.
And then in your twig template just do

```
{% render(controller('AcmeBundle:Controller:Action')) %}
```